# Xcode 4.3.1 on Mac 10.6.8

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, osx-leopard, ios5.1

I work on Mac 10.6 because I don't want to lose spaces to Lion. It's an extremely efficient part of my workflow. And I program for the iPad and need to write for iOS 5.1 and the new retina display, but for some reason apple has made the new Xcode only available for Mac 10.7 or later.

How can I either install the new Xcode, find a workable Xcode, or somehow install iOS 5.1 support into my current Xcode? (4.0.1)

Comment: My suggestion is to adapt your workflow to include newer components. In not doing so, you only set yourself up for a longer adjustment period once you absolutely have to make the transition.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that without cheat with Apple, you need to stay up to date !

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not fond of getting Lion until it includes spaces.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, you have to upgrade. Xcode 4.3 is coded with innovations that will only work on OS X Lion.

The cap was Xcode 4.2 that ran on SL. You will have to upgrade or continue only developing for older, legacy iOS versions (not a good option).